# Why TypeScript doesn't detect error when use undefined for boolean?

Tags: typescript

I have the interface:

```
interface Example {
  foo: boolean
}
```

later I use something like:

```
getFoo = (): Example => {foo: undefined}
```

without `ts` error. It is normal? If it is valid, is it good a practice to use `undefined` in situations like that?

Comment: `undefined` is always valid, regardless the property type. Same is with `null`.

Comment: there is an compiler flag option for that,

Comment: @briosheje not always, see my answer.

Comment: @Pac0: Oh. cool! didn't know that, very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will consider it as an error if you use the TypeScript (2.0+) compiler option

`--strict-null-checks`

in this case, `undefined` and/or `null` will be allowed only if you explicity state it with a union type :

```
interface Example {
  foo: boolean | null | undefined
}
```

Probably for backward compatibility issues, the default behavior was decided not to use strict checks.

more info here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html

---

for the use of `undefined`, I can't say if it's good or bad practice (I think more context is needed). However, you can use the optional interface fields with `?` :

```
interface Example {
  foo?: boolean
}
```